# Problem downloading photos from iPhone Photostream to Windows

Tags: iphone, icloud, windows, photo-stream

Why doesn't my iCloud panel on my Windows 8 computer always download the photos from Photostream on my iPhone?

I have an iPhone 5, on iOS 7.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Apple dropped the ball with the new iCloud services for Windows. I've had the exact same issue on 3 different machines and iPads/iPhones from different family members.

What worked for me:

1. Make a backup of your PhotoStream folder on your PC.
2. Open the Windows Task Manager (CTRL-SHIFT-ESC) and kill the following processes if they are listed:

   - iCloudService.exe
   - iCloud.exe
   - AplePhotoStreams.exe
   - ApplePhotoStreamDownloader.exe
   - APSDaemon.exe
3. Then go to the following locations and delete the whole folders (or move them somewhere else for backup):

   - Your photostream folder:
     `C:\Users\<YOURNAME>\Pictures\My Photo Stream`
   - Mediastream Data folder:
     `C:\Users\<YOURNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MediaStream`
4. Then run iCloud directly:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\iCloud.exe`

In theory, things should sync again with the following caveat:

- Only pictures taken in the last 30 days will be synced.
- At most 1000 pictures will be synced (if you took that many in the last 30 days).
- Try some of the other solutions from the Thread [My Photo Stream is empty with iCloud Control Panel 3.0](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23121156) from the Apple forums.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue! For almost 2 weeks, all the photos I have taken will not show up on the photo stream on the phone or on my computer.